# What is the minimum value of $\operatorname{trace}(AA^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A_{n\times n}$ be a non singular matrix, could any one tell me what is the minimum value of $\operatorname{trace}(AA^T)$

Comment: You seem to have enough experience here to know to provide your thoughts/ideas on how to solve the problem.

Comment: ...with the full answer given in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We note that if $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible then it is diagonalizable, that is to say: $\exists \mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that:

$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$$

Where $\mathbf{\Lambda}=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n})$ and $\lambda_{i}$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$. We also note that a necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathbf{A}$ to be invertible is that $\lambda_{i}\neq 0$, $\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. We also note that:

$$\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A})=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}$$

Moreover, we have that $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}^{T})=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A})$ and therefore:

$$\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{2}$$

As we can construct a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with arbitrary eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, we have that $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A})$ can take any value in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This is a bit more complicated than necessary. You can just assume $A$ to be diagonal with non-zero entries on the diagonal from the outright.

Comment: You can even assume A to have a single nonzero element in the top-left corner !

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write that the matrix was integer valued